# UILabel containing HTML/Attributed Text - how to scale when inside a UIScrollView

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uilabel, ios-autolayout

I do have a UIScrollView only containing a UILabel. The UILabel contains an NSAttributedString made out of HTML:

```
let str = try NSAttributedString(data: content.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
```

Now I would like to let the user zoom the label to have everything bigger. When only using

```
func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView?
```

everything works as expected, but the font gets blurry. I tried changing the font size after zooming:

```
func scrollViewDidEndZooming(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, with view: UIView?, atScale scale: CGFloat) {
    myLabel.setFontSize(pointSize: scrollView.zoomScale)
}
```

with the function being the following:

```
extension UILabel {
    func setFontSize(pointSize: CGFloat) {
        let fullRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: text!.count)
        let mutableAttributeText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attributedText!)
        mutableAttributeText.enumerateAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, in: fullRange, options: NSAttributedString.EnumerationOptions.longestEffectiveRangeNotRequired) {
        (attribute: Any!, range: NSRange, stop: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void in
        if let attributeFont = attribute as? UIFont {
            let newPointSize = 12 * pointSize
            let scaledFont = UIFont(descriptor: attributeFont.fontDescriptor, size: newPointSize)
            mutableAttributeText.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: scaledFont, range: range)
        }
    }
    attributedText = mutableAttributeText
}
```

}

But then the text is not positioned exactly the same as before. Now what's the best way to let the user zoom in and out and have the text still sharp? I'm using auto layout to position the label inside UIScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

@swalkner since you have to display a html, why not use a WKWebview instead of UIScrollView.

```
let htmlString = "some_html"
let webView:WKWebView = WKWebView.init(frame: frame)
webView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
self.view.addSubview(webView)
// load html
webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
```

And if the load html takes a little bit of time, you can simply try to preload the webview, by creating it and load the html before push or present the controller.

Comment: because 1) it takes longer to load, 2) scrolling is not nice with the gray background and 3) how does it help with zooming?

Comment: 1) totaly true, but you can preload the webview; 2) you can setup any kind of background on webview(webView.backgroundColor); 3) by default webiew allow zooming.

Comment: but regarding 3) if I zoom in and then zoom out pretty far, the text gets clipped and is only loaded again after letting to the pinch gesture, that's not really nice either...